# Need info on engine exchange 2007 malibu from 2.2 to the 3.5

Tags: engine

It's hard to find a reasonable priced 2.2 motor which is a v4.  The 3.5 L is more common  and cheaper.  What will need to be done to change from the 2.2 to the 3.5

Comment: It won't be cheaper to do the swap. It's almost never cheaper to swap to a different engine.

Answer (score 1):

cant find anyone doing this swap. Best thing to do is grab 3 monitors bring up a spreadsheet and 2 autozone web pages. go through part by part and see what is different between the 2 engine types. You really want to look at engine mounts, transmissions, steering boxes, radiator, fuel pumps, computers, wiring harnesses, half shafts, and anything else that looks like it will get in the way. The more items that are the same the better. Don't forget to look up all the accessories on the front of the engine like water pump, power steering, alternator, starter, AC and other things they may have tacked on. You then want to look at pictures of both the 2.2 and the 3.5 to see if you see any differences in mounting points, crossmembers, etc.

Might be easier to just go for it if you're dead set on doing the swap but for that car?